# Composer: class not found League\Uri\UriString

Tags: php, composer-php

My composer.json entry under `"require"` has this line:

```
    "league/uri-parser": "^1.4",
```

Links to the package:

- [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/league/uri-parser)
- [github.com](https://github.com/thephpleague/uri-parser)

I get an exception that the following class is missing: `League\Uri\UriString`

I also found that `v1.4.0` is not the latest version.

Things I've tried to update to the latest version

1. `composer remove league/uri-parser` followed by `composer require league/uri-parser`. It doesn't change anything
2. `composer update`. no change
3. `vendor/bin/composer dump-autoload -o`. No change.
4. `composer clearcache` and `composer upgrade` while the library was set to `*` and `^1.4` but terminal kept reporting "nothing to install or update"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which exact class is missing? Can you please provide more information on that missing class or the exception you're facing?

Comment: `League\Uri\UriString;` which is the first class mentioned in their documentation. When I try to run a test in PHPUunit using this class, I get a "Class not found" error pointing to this class. It also lints as not found in Phpstorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is named `League\Uri\Parser\UriString` in the current release (`v1.4.1`) of `league/uri-parser`.

The `\Parser\` part was removed **only** on the `master` branch but the latest release (`v1.4.1`) still uses the old namespace! ( See the [commit](https://github.com/thephpleague/uri-parser/commit/82a672dd7d517d30d3ce0853192009aac34f9eca) )

Use the correct class (`League\Uri\Parser\UriString`) and your issue will be resolved.